# Intellij 14.1.3 and SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-14

When the auto-import of SBT , it marks me " Unresolved dependency" , and I do not understand why !!!

Yet the jar files are in the directory .ivy2 .

Can you help me.

best regards, Alexis

Comment: Please, show us full SBT output and your build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

Try the EAP version if the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [a bug](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/463962?tstart=0). Perhaps more success joining that discussion on devnet.jetbrains.com.